# Cannot installing blackberry webwork plugin using eclipse update site

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-webworks

I am creating blackberry development environment. i installed following:
1. oracle jdk 1.7
2. Blackberry java eclipse plugin1.5.2.
 when i installing blackberry webworks plugin using update site :

```
    http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web
```

or

```
  http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.6/web
```

but i'm not able to install its giving some error like this:

```
 Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.0.0.201103231828-18   
   (net.rim.browser.tools.wcpc.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.201103231828-18)
```

Please anyone provide exact link for insatllation if available. If not available then tell me how to create blackberry webwork development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The support for the Blackberry webworks plugin has been discontinued.
Please follow these steps to develop a phonegap application using blackberry

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry

Comment: Thanks,for response. As i know on this site given only for command line only.

Answer (score 0):

Update: You can also now use the Ripple mobile emulator to build a BlackBerry WebWorks application.

Simply install the WebWorks SDK, configure Ripple and click the "Package" button.

Here is a video that shows how to get started with Ripple: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nj_N7gWjbzs